# Executing the ls | wc linux command in c program using 2 processes communicating trough a pipe

Tags: c, linux, process, pipe, dup

I'm currently having problems with the following exercise:

I want to "mimic" the pipe command line `ls | wc` in linux bash with the following program.
What I do is:

- create a pipe
- create a reader child and writer child
- the writer child closes the pipe's reading side and redirects his stdout to the writing side of the pipe
- the reader child closes the pipe's writing side and makes the reading side of the pipe his stdin
- both children do an exec, the writer executes the `ls` program, passes the output through the pipe to the reader that executes the `wc` program on that output.

When I do `ls | wc` in linux terminal I get the following result:

```
8      8     101
```

But if I execute my program I get the following result:

```
0      0      0
```

Here is my program:

```
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <errno.h> 
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h> 
#include <sys/types.h> 
#include <sys/stat.h> 
#include <fcntl.h> 
#include <string.h> 
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <libgen.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main(void){
        int mypipe[2];
        pid_t pid1, pid2;

        if (pipe(mypipe)<0)
                perror ("pipe error"), exit(1);
        if ((pid1=fork())<0)
                perror ("fork error"), exit(1);

        else if (pid1==0) {
                //reader child
                close (mypipe[1]);
                if (dup2(mypipe[0], STDIN_FILENO)!=STDIN_FILENO)
                        perror ("dup2 error"), exit(1);
                close (mypipe[0]); 
                if (execlp("wc", "wc", NULL)<0)
                        perror("execlp1 error"), exit(1);
                else {  //pid >0, parent
                        if ((pid2=fork())<0)
                                perror ("fork error"), exit(2);
                        else if (pid2==0) {     
                                //writer child
                                close(mypipe[0]);
                                if (dup2(mypipe[1], STDOUT_FILENO) != STDOUT_FILENO)
                                        perror("dup2 error"), exit(1);
                                close (mypipe[1]);
                                if (execlp("ls", "ls", NULL)<0)
                                        perror ("execlp error"), exit(1);
                        }
                        else {  //parent
                                close(mypipe[0]);
                                close(mypipe[1]);

                                waitpid(pid1, NULL, 0);
                                waitpid(pid2, NULL, 0);
                                exit(0);
                        }
                }
        }
return 0;
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance for the answers!

Comment: Note that if `execlp()` (or any other `exec*()` function) succeeds, it doesn't return; if it returns, it failed.  There's no need to test the return value.  Although in this case it probably doesn't matter, it is generally a good idea to `exit()` — or `_exit()` — after printing an error.

Comment: `if (execlp("wc", "wc", NULL)<0)` everything after that line will not run when `execlp` succeeds. But you have the second `fork` in the `else` of that `if`. The code indentation should alert you do that. That's not what you want. You need to pair `else {  //pid >0, parent` with `else if (pid1==0)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is confused.  You have many irrelevant headers, and repeat `#include <errno.h>`.  In the `main()` function, you have:

```
int main(void)
{
    int mypipe[2];
    pid_t pid1, pid2;

    if (pipe(mypipe) < 0)
        perror("pipe error"), exit(1);
    if ((pid1 = fork()) < 0)
        perror("fork error"), exit(1);
    else if (pid1 == 0)
    {   
        // reader child
        close(mypipe[1]);
        if (dup2(mypipe[0], STDIN_FILENO) != STDIN_FILENO)
            perror("dup2 error"), exit(1);
        close(mypipe[0]);
        if (execlp("wc", "wc", NULL) < 0)
            perror("execlp1 error"), exit(1);
        else            // pid >0, parent
        {   
            …
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The `else if (pid1 == 0)` clause is executed by the child.  It closes the write end of the pipe, duplicates the read end to standard input and closes the read end of the pipe.  It then does `execlp()` on `wc`.  Only if the code fails to execute `wc` will the `else` clause be executed, and then there is only the read end of the pipe left open.  Meanwhile, the original process simply exits.  That closes the pipe, so the `wc` command gets no input, and reports `0 0 0` as a result.

You need to rewrite the code.  The parent process should wait until both its children execute.  Especially while debugging, you should not ignore the exit status of children, and you should report it.

Here's some code that works.  Note that it avoids bushy decision trees — it is a linear sequence of `if` / `else if` / … / `else` code.  This is easier to understand, in general, than a bushy, multi-level set of conditions.

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void)
{
    int fd[2];
    pid_t pid1, pid2;

    if (pipe(fd) < 0)
        perror("pipe error"), exit(1);
    else if ((pid1 = fork()) < 0)
        perror("fork error"), exit(1);
    else if (pid1 == 0)
    {
        /* ls */
        dup2(fd[1], STDOUT_FILENO);
        close(fd[0]);
        close(fd[1]);
        execlp("ls", "ls", (char *)0);
        perror("exec ls");
        exit(1);
    }
    else if ((pid2 = fork()) < 0)
        perror("fork error"), exit(1);
    else if (pid2 == 0)
    {
        /* wc */
        dup2(fd[0], STDIN_FILENO);
        close(fd[0]);
        close(fd[1]);
        execlp("wc", "wc", (char *)0);
        perror("exec wc");
        exit(1);
    }
    else
    {
        close(fd[0]);
        close(fd[1]);
        int status1;
        int status2;
        int corpse1 = waitpid(pid1, &status1, 0);
        int corpse2 = waitpid(pid2, &status2, 0);
        printf("ls: pid = %d, corpse = %d, exit status = 0x%.4X\n", pid1, corpse1, status1);
        printf("ls: pid = %d, corpse = %d, exit status = 0x%.4X\n", pid2, corpse2, status2);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

A sample run of the program `pipe41` on my machine produced:

```
$ pipe41
     175     175    1954
ls: pid = 44770, corpse = 44770, exit status = 0x0000
ls: pid = 44771, corpse = 44771, exit status = 0x0000
$ ls | wc
     175     175    1954
$
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I'll treasure all your corrections, from now on I'll write the clearest code I can!